# not sure why I can access this array value with objectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, ios

not an objective-c programmer but am not sure why I can't access this value:

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[colorsArray addObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[colorsArray addObject:[UIColor blueColor]];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor [colorsArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

I get an `expected identifier` but syntax looks ok to me. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line should be:

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[colorsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

You put color instances into the array, so you should just use that to get them out.

I think the confusion comes from the calling of UIColor class methods `whiteColor` and ´blueColor` in the lines before. In Objective-C, a message is sent by identifying the receiver *class* or *instance* and then specifying the *selector* part in brackets.

Comment: thx, would something like the above edit be possible? Couldn't get this to work either

Comment: Yes, you can do what you suggest, but you have to leave out the UIColor part. You are not calling a method on UIColor, you are calling a method on the array.

Comment: ok - that seemed to be crashing. I'll delete that edit out and ask new question. thx d

Comment: @timpone, No that wont work that way. You will get a string there and that is not same as a method call.